# Gridview event is not firing for some rows

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

I am displaying a summary page inside the Gridview. Everything is working fine except the last 3 rows of the gridview rowcommand event is not firing when i click on it.

Below is the aspx code which i used for commandargument.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUnpaid" runat="server"  Text='<%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Unpaid_Claims")).ToString("#,##0.00") %>' 

CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Companyid")+ ";" +Eval("TypeOf")+ ";" +Eval("BranchID")+ ";" +Eval("CategoryID") %>' CommandName="Unpaid"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Below is the code generate inside HTML

```
<tr style="background-color:White;">
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td align="right">
        <span id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl28_lblCategory">预付手机费</span>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl28_lnkTotal" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$gvSummary$ctl28$lnkTotal','')">5,620.00</a>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl28_lnkApproved" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$gvSummary$ctl28$lnkApproved','')">5,620.00</a>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl28_lnkPending" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$gvSummary$ctl28$lnkPending','')">0.00</a>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl28_lnkpaid" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$gvSummary$ctl28$lnkpaid','')">200.00</a>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl28_lnkUnpaid" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$gvSummary$ctl28$lnkUnpaid','')">5,420.00</a>                                 
    </td>
</tr>


<tr style="background-color:#E3EAEB;">
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td align="right">
        <span id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl29_lblCategory">预支薪金</span>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl29_lnkTotal" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$gvSummary$ctl29$lnkTotal','')">5,075.00</a>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl29_lnkApproved" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$gvSummary$ctl29$lnkApproved','')">5,075.00</a>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl29_lnkPending" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$gvSummary$ctl29$lnkPending','')">0.00</a>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl29_lnkpaid" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$gvSummary$ctl29$lnkpaid','')">5,075.00</a>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <a id="ctl00_Main_gvSummary_ctl29_lnkUnpaid" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$gvSummary$ctl29$lnkUnpaid','')">0.00</a>                                 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Below is screen shot.The area which marked in Red is not firing upon click.
![Error in Griddiew   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D43tk.png)

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Instead of generated html show us the code for gridview

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sSp_Calculate", myConnection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userid", Session["UserId"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", month);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", year);

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ResultsTable);

        ResultsTable=FilterDT(ResultsTable);

        gvSummary.DataSource = ResultsTable;
        gvSummary.DataBind();